# angular ng-repeat add text to the first item inside the select options

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to add a text "primary" to the select options dropdown, where the text primary should be applied only to the 1st item of the options or if a new user is added he should be primary.

```
in HTML

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select>
  <option ng-repeat="names in name">{{names.name}} - {{names.id}} <span ng-if="$first">primary</span></option>
  </select>
</div>

in Controller

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = [{name:"jack",id:1},{name:"jill",id:2},{name:"nick",id:3},{name:"homes",id:4},{name:"jhones",id:5},{name:"james",id:6}];
}
```

[JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/10911/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to put a `<span>` inside of an `<option>` which isn't allowed with html. While your fiddle is using Angular 1.0.1, after angular 1.1.5 they added the ability to use a ternary operator. Using that we can accomplish what you intend:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select>
  <option ng-repeat="names in name">{{names.name}} - {{names.id}} {{$first ? 'primary' : ''}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Hopefully that can help steer you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Lucas it was really helpful... :)